# Java M3 declaration nodes with unknown source location

Tags: rascal

Whilst attempting to perform AST based type 2 clone detection, I encountered the following:

```
class TestEnum {
    enum Level {
        LOW,
        MEDIUM,
        HIGH
    }
}
```

When visiting the AST obtained with `createAstFromFile`, from a file that contains only the example above. 
The class and enum nodes representing line 1 and 2 have the default unknown source location (`|unknown:///|`). Whereas lines 3 through 5 will be represented by enumConstants with their 
source location set as expected.

What causes the class and enum nodes to have no actual source location set? What is a valid approach to finding all AST nodes which start on a specific line?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Could you file an issue on GitHub with this example?